# Is a connection from my SSL-secured server to an RDS instance automatically encrypted when using mysqli_connect?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysqli

I'm trying to determine if I need to use mysqli_ssl_set to encrypt my db layer. I have a standard Amazon RDS instance that I'm connecting to with MySQL user and pass, but I'm unsure if that connection is automatically encrypted. My server is SSL-ready, but does that mean mysqli_connect is encrypted by default?

This is my code right now:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(self::$host, self::$user, self::$password);
self::$lastConnection = $connection;
$db = "db_prod";
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8mb4");
```

Do I need to add in mysqli_ssl_set too?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to call

```
mysqli_ssl_set(connection, key, cert, ca, capath, cipher)
```

or

```
$mysqli -> ssl_set(key, cert, ca, capath, cipher)
```

see manual
https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.ssl-set.php

or https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_ssl_set.asp

Comment: I'm using Letsencrypt for my SSL. Would you happen to know how to fill in mysqli_ssl_set? I tried this: mysqli_ssl_set($con, "/var/lib/mysql/privkey.pem", "/var/lib/mysql/cert.pem", "/var/lib/mysql/chain.pem", NULL, NULL); but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you all those files correctly add to the server . Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';`and see also there could be a tls problem.